# Is there any tool that can do event logging for Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, logging

I have a website that is built with Visualforce page and apex. I want to have logging feature added to the apex (trace, debug, info, ...eror, fatal). I know you can do this using debug log but my question is `is there any available free or **PAID** tool out there that you can install/plugin to ease/better the process?` For example, something that is similar to `log4net, log4j...` but for Salesforce?

Comment: I don't think so, and probably a definite "no" for free options...but I'd be interested in any answers. You could implement one yourself: create a Logger class and essentially create custom object "Logs" to store the information in. You could have it write different types based on different methods (debug, exception, info, etc).

Comment: If you are willing to use a paid tool you can look at salesforce event monitoring. It gives you the information you want.

Comment: If there isn't a freebie then I am wiling to pay for a service/app, too.

Comment: This would be a great starting point
https://succeedwithsalesforce.com/creating-persistent-logs-using-apex-and-a-custom-object/